# Find as close as exact matches in database - which way is better?

Tags: mysql, search, csv

I have a situation:

I have a database (MySQL) which contains products and their codes like this

```
BLACK SUGAR BS 709
HOT SAUCE AX889/9
TOMY 8861
```

I got an excel spreadsheet which I converted to CSV, this contains prices for the products. Its structure consists in 2 columns, code and price, like this:

```
BS709          23.00
AX 889 /9      10.89
8861           1.69
```

I made a script to update the products prices by searching in the database for the respective product code, using a FOREACH and %LIKE% query.

FOREACH row in CSV, search the database using "WHERE product_code LIKE %code%.

This is offcourse a primitive and not so succesfull way of updating the prices, because the codes in CSV are not an exact match (in syntax) of those in the database so if I have two products in the DB containing BS709 (BS70923) in their code I get multiple matches.

Is there a better way of doing this ?

Comment: the first step is database agnostic. You have to define a matching algorithm. Ask yourself the right questions (e.g. does BS 709 have to match BS709?). Then you could have a look to the FULLTEXT search methods of mysql (`MATCH` etc.)

Comment: Keep in mind that MySQL is not case sensitive, that could either be a blessing or a curse in your case.

Comment: I will look into FULLTEXT

Answer (score 0):

You could trim the columns of spaces and other characters using MySQL [`replace()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) before comparing. This will return all exact matches, regardless of any spaces contained.

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE REPLACE( product_code, ' ', '' ) LIKE 'code'`

Comment: I do use TRIM to remove spaces and characters, the problem is with products that have a similar code, like when searching for BS 709 and in the database I have products BS 709 and BS 7092, BS 709/2. All three match.

Comment: If you eliminate the wildcard, and search for "BS 709" it will match only "BS 709", not the others. See, I have not used `%` in my query. And TRIM is nice, but it's only manipulating beginning or trailing spaces (not spaces part-way through a string)

Comment: I meant REPLACE not TRIM, sorry.

Yes, but I still have to use wildcard because in the database the column also contains "BLACK SUGAR", "TOMY", etc, pactically the column cotain "NAME + code". What if I use something like %LIKE, only a front wildcard, that would deal with the prefix text ?

Scenario:
In the database lets say I have these:

`BLACK SUGAR BS709
BLACK SUGAR BS7092
BLACK SUGAR BS70`

Using %LIKE% BS709 I get the first two !
Using %LIKE BS709 I get only the first one, I think its ok ? No ?

Comment: Yes, exactly right. But: you still might get duplicates if `LIKE '% BS709'` there still is a wildcard up front and so you might return results like "BROWN SUGAR BS709" but you know your data better than I do, if there's no cases like that, it might work :)

Answer (score 0):

Given your examples, I would recommend removing all spaces from both, and then just looking for when the beginning or end of a code matches exactly:

```
where replace(e.code, ' ', '') like concat(replace(db.code, ' ', ''), '%') or
      replace(e.code, ' ', '') like concat('%', replace(db.code, ' ', '')) or
      replace(db.code, ' ', '') like concat(replace(e.code, ' ', ''), '%') or
      replace(db.code, ' ', '') like concat('%', replace(e.code, ' ', ''));
```

This may not work for the specific case when one code is a prefix of another.

In any case, if the product codes in a spreadsheet are different from the product codes in the database, I think you have bigger problems.  If you cannot really fix the spreadsheets, I would recommend that you manually/semi-automatically create a synonyms table in the database.  This would have the Excel product code in one column and the correct product code in the other.  Then you can do the lookup just by joining this together.

Yes.  That is work.  But probably less work than struggling with this problem and getting poor results that have to be repeatedly updated.